# What additional considerations need to be made in regression for time series problems?

Tags: regression, time-series

I think I have a good idea of how linear regression using OLS and the regularized variants works from reading posts on here and reading Elements of Statistical Learning, but most posts here and in ESL use standard examples with $y$ and some set of predictors and it's not usually in the context of time series analysis.

So my question here is when regression is applied to time series data, what additional considerations do we need to take into account, and how does this differ for applying regression methods to more standard non-time series problems?